# Autodesk Platform Services PKCE Authentication Failing

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge, pkce

I am making an internal React.js/Node.js Autodesk SPA to automate pieces of our current workflow and am having issues when it comes to the PKCE auth flow.

After following their documented tutorial, I'm either doing something incorrectly or another piece is failing elsewhere down the line.

I am successfully receiving an authorization code from Autodesk, during the exchange I am getting one of two errors. The first is a 400 invalid_grant "The Authorization code is invalid or has timed out" which is self-explanatory, and the second is a 400 invalid_grant "PKCE verification failed" which is a little more vague as to what is going on. At this point, I would be expecting the Autodesk server to return the access token.

I have made sure that I am passing the correct Authorization code during the exchange so in the first case it must be a timeout, however, I am lost on the second error. I'm sure it's something very simple but I am just needing a second opinion.

Comment: Sorry for long wait. We're investigating this behavior and I'll update you here.

Comment: Share your code! It's going to be hard for someone to figure out what went wrong if you don't share a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a sample so you can test PKCE workflow with your own client id.

Please give it a try at https://joaomartins-callmejohn.github.io/PKCE-TEST/

Here's the repo with all the resources it was based https://github.com/JoaoMartins-callmeJohn/PKCE-TEST

Comment: This is not really a good answer, because the answer should contain the solution, not link to an external site. Furthermore, the external site is a complete OAuth2 client and doesn't directly solve OP's problem. That said, there's also not a lot of details in the original question which will make it hard to give an answer that's actually good.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest at least trying to embed your answer here, and maybe use a tested 3rd party OAuth2 client instead of embedding something from scratch.